# how to send a size of array when i allocate a dynamic array C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to send size to a dynamic array, by calling a function, and set the size using the argument `SIZE` I sent while calling the function.
for example:

That's the function I create my dynamic array in:

```
JumboPacket(IN OUT UINT8* &p_buffer, ***IN UINT8  size***, IN MACAddress src, IN MACAddress dst)
{
    UINT8 *my_buff_to_send = new UINT8[size] { 0 };
}
```

Now i call the function with arguments:

```
JumboPacket( p_buffer, **7000**, MAC_LinkPartner, MAC_DUT);
```

why do i get a wired number  in ***IN UINT8  size*** im expecting in this case to get **7000**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The maximum value that can be stored in an object of the type UINT8 is equal to 255.

Comment: 7000 in decimal is 0x1B58 hex. You got the truncated 0x58 thing which was 88.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) has commented - you are using a UINT8 variable type as an input.

UINT8 is a declaration for using an 8 bit based, unsigned integer type of variable. This means you can place a value which uses up to 8 bits in order to be represented.

In this case, the maximum value for a UINT8 type variable will be 2^8 - 1, or 255 (and the minimum is, of course 0).

More on this greek bitology can be found [here](http://mechdc.blogspot.co.il/2010/05/type-modifiers.html).

Be careful not to overload this variable with more bits then it can store!!